# How to get nested value from list

Tags: ansible, jmespath, json-query

I'm having trouble to get ID from json code that mutch a specific value in such array
I explain:
I have this code json:

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "TAB": "bleu",
      "exp": [
        {
          "A": "NOT_PROTECTED",
          "B": [
            "500",
            "600"
          ],
          "C": false
        }
      ],
      "ID": "000041"
    },
    {
      "TAB": "rouge",
      "exp": [
        {
          "A": "PROTECTED",
          "B": [
            "700",
            "800"
          ],
          "C": true
        }
      ],
      "ID": "000042"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the question is how you access the values in Ansible, since it has the ansible tag.

You can use the map filter in Ansible to access the values like so: (where your json is in the `some_json` variable.)

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ some_json.results | map(attribute='ID') | list }}"
```

results:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => {  
    "msg": [          
        "000041",     
        "000042"      
    ]                 
}
```

If you want to do it with `json_query/jmespath` (As the question is also tagged with `json_query` and `jmespath`) then it would be like this:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ some_json.results | json_query('[*].ID') | list }}"
```

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [        
        "000041",   
        "000042"    
    ]               
}
```

That being said, I do prefer the `map` method myself since it does not require any extra dependencies where as `json_query` requires `jmespath` to be installed.

Comment: actually it's not what I want exactly, your code is juste get all IDs, but what I want is to get an ID that mutch B[0] = 500 , like in this example, I want to get as result :  00041 because it's B[0] = 500